# Ways to power a laptop motherboard directly?

Tags: power, motherboard, laptop

I would like to power a laptop motherboard from a lenovo y580 without using the laptops own power system. I am having trouble finding the information I need. Do laptop motherboards have the same power input specs as desktop motherboards? Like could an atx power supply be used to power one?

Comment: No ATX will almost certainly not work with any laptop, at the very least because of the connector[s].

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any standard.

Looking at the service manual it seems that the laptop you are talking about doesn't have any seperate power boards. So it's probablly just a matter of connecting a power supply to the motherboard in the same way you would if it was in the laptop.

The service manual for your laptop can be found at http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_y480_y580_hmm_1st_edition_mar_2012_english.pdf

Comment: Got a link to the service manual?

Comment: http://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_y480_y580_hmm_1st_edition_mar_2012_english.pdf

Comment: Whoever downvoted this (@Journeyman Geek?) what laptop mobo power standards can you name?

Comment: I did not. I felt it was a perfectly fine answer which the additional information would improve. My comments would be *significantly* more critical should I have chosen to downvote.